# VBS with Space in File Path

Tags: vbscript

This is what I have and can not get the bat to run, if I move the bat to a folder without spaces in the name it works. My problem is that the actual bat is in a folder with spaces, so I need this to work.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("%comspec% /K C:\Program Files\ping.bat"), 1, True
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to quote the file specification:

```
Run("%comspec% /K ""C:\Program Files\ping.bat""")
```

Comment: This did not work for me in Windows 10 1909 `WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run("%comspec% /K ""\\NETWORK\Test Folder""")`
It opens CMD and can't find "string before space". This does work but I need something with spaces `WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run("\\NETWORK\TestFolder")`

Comment: @DGM There is nothing wrong with the command, the issue is you can't access a UNC path from the command prompt. You're so-called workaround is not using the command prompt which is why it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a directory path in a VBScript that had empty spaces:

E.g.

The following did not work:

```
objShell.Run("C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\bin\netbeans64.exe")
```

I simply included two extra double quotations on either side of the path and it worked for me:

```
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\bin\netbeans64.exe""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = chr(34)&"%comspec% /K C:\Program Files\ping.bat"&chr(34)
objShell.Run strCommand,1,True
```

Answer (score -3):

I know that this is an old question, but I found a fix that works for me.
It's the double quotes you need.
Try below:

```
objShell.Run("%comspec% /K " & """C:\Program Files\ping.bat""""), 1, True);
```