# The system cannot find the file if its path/name contains a space

Tags: vbscript, windows-10

```
Path = split(wscript.scriptFullName, wscript.scriptname)(0) 
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run(Path & "Name.txt")
```

The above script works fine if both the file path and file name contain no spaces.

If either contains a space, the result will be;

> Error: The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBS with Space in File Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360599/vbs-with-space-in-file-path)

Comment: You could also use the `BuildPath()` method of the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to avoid this issue altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are fairly simple:

1. All strings have to start and end with double quotes to be a valid string.

   ```
   Dim a
   a = "Hello World" 'Valid string.
   a = "Hello World  'Not valid and will produce an error.
   ```
2. Any use of variables must use the [String Concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) character `&` to combine them with strings.

   ```
   Dim a: a = "Hello"
   Dim b
   b = a & " World" 'Valid concatenated string.
   b = a " World"   'Not valid and will produce an error.
   ```
3. As double quotes are used to define a string, all instances of double quotes inside a string must be escaped by doubling the quotes `""` but Rule 1. still applies.

   ```
   Dim a: a = "Hello"
   Dim b
   b = """" & a & " World""" 'Valid escaped string.
   b = """ & a & " World"""  'Not valid, start of string is not complete 
                             'after escaping the double quote 
                             'producing an error.
   ```

Follow these three rules and you won't go far wrong.

With those in mind the above line would need to be;

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run("""" & Path & "Name.txt""")
```

to generate a string surrounded by literal double quotes.

---

#### Useful Links

- [VBS with Space in File Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360599/vbs-with-space-in-file-path)
- [Adding quotes to a string in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2942554/692942)
- [Breaking a String Across Multiple Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37565683/692942) *(More on string concatenation)*.

Comment: IMO, this would have been better as an answer on the [potential dup-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360599/vbs-with-space-in-file-path) you proposed and closing this question as a duplicate. Having it here confuses the issue of which question should be the dup-target.

Answer (score -3):

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run(""""Path & "Name.txt""")
```

is how.

Comment: Removed a quote.

Comment: Think you mean `CreateObject("wscript.shell").run("""" & Path & "Name.txt""")`. You had it right the first time but didn't concatenate the `Path` variable afterwards. Its also been answered numerous times before, flag and move on.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: @Noodles You're right about that but still you're missing the `&` between `""""` and `Path`. Obviously not basic enough.

Comment: Yes, there is much to learn even from such simple lines. If you had never used such lines before (cause you've just started to learn a new programming language), it's absolutely neccessary to see some explanation